# OSGi Declarative Services ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE equivalent in aries blueprint

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi

In declarative services, one can set component(service) configuration policy to "REQUIRE", to make it dependent to existence of a certain config file. that means the service will not be created until the configuration with the matching "pid" is available in config admin.

Is there a similar solution in blueprint?

I have tried the managed-service-factory, but since I need only ONE instance of my service, I don't know how to make sure the factory only creates one instance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for an answer to this myself, and found nothing except this  (very old) question!).

My solution is to

1. create a dummy declarative service with  `configurationPolicy=REQUIRE`
2. declare a `<reference ...'/>` to this dummy service in blueprint (making blueprint wait until my dummy service is started.

In this way blueprint doesn't complete its startup until the relevant configuration exists. It feels like a bit of hack, and registers a pointless service.